# How to fix the plot of the symbolic eigenvalues of the 1st matrix (matlab)?

Tags: matlab, plot, linear-algebra, symbolic-math

I'm calculating the eigenvalues of a 8x8-matrix including a symbolic variable "W". Plotting the 8 eigenvalues as functions of W returns a strange result in the plot which looks like someone rode his bike over my diagram.

For the 2nd matrix, where I just set some off-diagonal elements equal to 0, everything works fine. But I don't know what the problem with the 1st one is.

```matlab
syms W;

w0=1/780;
wl=1/1064;
h=1; % for now this seems unnecessary, but I want to change this value later on

% This is the 1st matrix which causes some strange plotting results
A=h*[w0+3*wl 2*W 0 0 0 sqrt(3)*W 0 0;
    2*W 4*wl 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 2*wl+w0 sqrt(3)*W 0 0 0 sqrt(2)*W;
    0 0 sqrt(3)*W 3*wl 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 wl+w0 sqrt(2)*W 0 0;
    sqrt(3)*W 0 0 0 sqrt(2)*W 2*wl 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 w0 W;
    0 0 sqrt(2)*W 0 0 0 W wl];

% This is the 2nd matrix for which everything is working fine
B=h*[w0+3*wl 2*W 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    2*W 4*wl 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 2*wl+w0 sqrt(3)*W 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 sqrt(3)*W 3*wl 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 wl+w0 sqrt(2)*W 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 sqrt(2)*W 2*wl 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 w0 W;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 W wl];

X = eig(A);
X2 = eig(B);
eva22 = X2(1);
eva1 = X(1);

figure(1);

fplot(X2,[-0.002 0.002]);
hold on;
fplot(X,[-0.002 0.002]);
hold off;
xlabel('Rabi frequency [THz]','FontSize',11);
ylabel('dressed states','FontSize',11);
grid on;
box on;
```

I'm expecting the plot for matrix A to just be similar to the plot of matrix B, but somehow it doesn't work properly. I'd appreciate some tips and tricks how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second plot looks like that because the eigenvalues of B are imaginary. When using plot(), it plots the real part of complex numbers by default, but apparently fplot() doesn't. You can do `fplot(real(X), [-0.002 0.002])` instead to plot just the real part of the eigenvalues (assuming that's what you want).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the solution I was looking for. I just didn't realize that there's an imaginary part which needs to be cut off in order to get a reasonable plot.